# Generic Elastic Search Method c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the Nest.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/6.1.0

I have the following code:

```
    public class foo
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
    }

    public class foo2
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
    }


    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetDocumentAsync<T>(Guid id) where T: class
    {
        var searchResponse = _client.Search<T>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.id) //f.id is not a property of T
                    .Query(id.ToString())
                )
            )
        );

        return searchResponse.Documents;
    }
```

Question: How can I pass the field in as Id? I am aware I could make an interface however I don't have access to the classes. Is there another way to map it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is generic, if you want to use specific properties, you need to use a non-generic method or add a constraint that gives you the `Id` property. For example, have an interface like this:

```
public interface IHasId
{
    Guid id { get; }
}
```

Which makes your models look like this:

```
public class foo : IHasId
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
}

public class foo2 : IHasId
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
}
```

And now your method would have an updated constraint:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetDocumentAsync<T>(Guid id)
    where T : class, IHasId // <--- Add this
{
    // Snip
}
```